# update react application config from cypress test

Tags: reactjs, cypress, e2e-testing

I am trying to create some e2e tests for my react application and some behavior is dictated by a json config file from the application. Is there a way to update that json file before a cypress test is executed? I was thinking at `BeforeEach` hook, but I don't know how to update that file so that I can cover as much as possible scenarios with my tests.

I am using react 16.14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to update the json file before the app is started (before `cy.visit()`) presuming React reads the file on startup and not after the user takes an action.

Ref [cy.readFile()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/readfile#JSON)

> For JSON, the contents yielded are parsed into JavaScript and returned

```js
describe('test my app', () => {

  before(() => {
    cy.readFile('app-start.json').then(data => {
      // modify the data objext
      cy.writeFile('app-start.json', data)
    })
  })

  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('/')
  })
  ...
})
```